# .htaccess URLs title in url and id

Tags: php

I have some PHP watching anime page, and I am not exactly sure how to make the URL appear as the name of that anime.

Here is an example of what I would like to do: lets say some watch.php?id=animeid&title=AnimteTile and the title of that page is AnimeTile.
Instead of site.com/watch/watch.php?id=animeid&title=AnimteTile I would like the url to appear as site.com/watch/animename/id

Considering the setup I described, is there a way to make the urls appear as the names of the anime and id? And also, if someone links to that page by using the better looking url with the name of the page instead of the id, is there still a way to get the id and by that, the rest of the page contents?

Thanks!!

Comment: Look into modrewrite if you're using apache as your web server

Comment: i suppose something like this would help you achieve what you want : `RewriteRule ^watch/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ watch/watch.php?title=$1&id=$2`

Comment: i got Object not found! when i do that